# Accessing all metrics for a Project on OpenShift

Tags: curl, openshift-origin, hawkular

I am running openshift vm.

when I run this command on command prompt:

```
curl -k -X GET https://hawkular-metrics.example.com/hawkular/metrics/status
```

I am getting JSON object:

```
{"MetricsService":"STARTED","Implementation-Version":"0.12.0.Final"...}
```

But I want to access all metrics for a project.

https://github.com/openshift/origin-metrics/blob/master/docs/hawkular_metrics.adoc#accessing-all-metrics-for-a-project

How can I run the command like this link?
I want to run all command outside ssh session.
I am not sure about Authorization.
If I run this command inside ssh session, I am getting forbidden error.

I need your help.

Comment: You have to be authenticated and perform 'oc whoami -t'. This token will be used as XXXX. Than it will be possible to perform the command.